zsh split string on vertical tab
I have a program that generates output that contains vertical tabs. In zsh, vertical tabs obtained through the output of a program are somehow slightly different than vertical tabs that are typed in at the terminal. The following program demonstrates this:
# Create two variables with the same content (both with a vertical tab)
# However one is from a string literal and the other is created using a program 
a='a\vb'
echo -n "$a" > a.tmp
b="$(cat a.tmp)"

# The hexdump of the two variables is the same
echo -n "$a" | hexdump -C
echo -n "$b" | hexdump -C

# However, they are not equal to each other
[[ "$a" == "$b" ]] && echo "equal" || echo "not equal"

# And the second variable cannot be split on the vertical tab
echo -n "${(@s:\v:)a}" | hexdump -C
echo -n "${(@s:\v:)b}" | hexdump -C

So, the variables have the same content (as check by the hexdump) but are not equal and in particular the vertical tab is somehow not an actual vertical tab in the second variable (since it cannot be split on).
How can I split the second string on the psuedo-vertical tab? What character is it actually?
zsh version is zsh-5.9-0-g73d3173 running on macOS with nothing extra installed (no Oh-My-ZSH). I cannot change the output of the program to not contain vertical tabs. I have considered using tr to convert the vertical tabs but the program can generate most other characters and those shouldn't be separated on.

Debugging trick: printf '[%02x]' \'${^${(s..)var}}; print outputs the hex values of the characters in a string and avoids the eccentricities of echo or print.

@Gairfowl that's exactly how I figured out the fact they were literal '\v' and not vertical tabs.

Note that a vertical tab can be represented in zsh by $'\v'.

The \v is literally a slash followed by a v. It is the echo that evaluates the \v which is why hexdump sees them the same. Apparently, it does not need the -e to interpret the backslashes.
The reason the split doesn't work is that it doesn't interpret the backslashes, however it can be changed to ps which causes the split string to interpret backslashes as per https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html ("p - Recognize the same escape sequences as the print builtin").
So the split is rewritten as:
"${(@ps:\v:)a}"

